# Invoke-command with script return blank data

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, invoke-command

I follow a powershell for penetration testing course and I must use Invoke-command to remotely find words like password, username, credentials in txt file so i make this script called juicyinfo.ps1

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\Desktop\*.txt | Select-String -Pattern password, username, credentials
```

When I run it with this command:

```
Invoke-Command -FilePath 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Exercises\Pentester Academy\powershell\juicyinfo.ps1' -ComputerName 192.168.2.32 -Credential adminSMBtest
```

Or directly with scriptblock:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\Desktop\*.txt | Select-String -Pattern password, username, credentials  } -ComputerName 192.168.2.32 -Credential adminSMBtest
```

But that return blank line like the data is return but with blank lines. I explain more clearly, if I put 50 lines in a txt file with words username, password on the remote computer, I have an output of 50 blank lines for the results of Invoke-Command, if I put 10 lines I have an output of 10 lines...

Locally the script return correct output.

Others scripts like a simple helloworld or Get-process | findstr powershell works perfectly with invoke-command, I tried to ouput to a file and I still have file written with blank line.

Comment: Like that you're not actually reading the files content. 
Try to use Get-ChildItem ... | Get-Content | Select-String ...

Comment: That is pure formatting problem. The way formatting is defined for `MatchInfo` objects is not compatible with remoting serialization. All properties are here: `Invoke-Command … | Format-List`.

Comment: @PetSerAl - it's obvious now you mention it but I've been bitten by this just this morning :)

Comment: @PetSerAl you are the man!! thanks for your help, all works fine now.